# Git get change from a specific branch to work on mine

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I work on a project with git.
We have our master branch and each developers works on a specific branch and then with a pull request we merge to master.

So I work on branch A
My friend on branch B

I need the code in B to continue my work on A. however we can not merge B to master because the developers who do the merge is on vacation.
Is there any way I can have access to B without merging anything ?

Thanks

Comment: just merge B into A

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this after your colleague pushed all the changes you need:

```
git pull origin B
git checkout A
git merge B
```

But you need to be careful when you file the merge requests, because your branch `A` will contain the changes from `B` that you merged and they will go to `master` once your merge request is accepted.
So if the feature on branch `B` is incomplete when you merge it and later you merge `A` into `master`, the incomplete feature from branch `B` will be on `master` as well.
So if you do that, I'd suggest you hold of with the merge request for `A` until `B` is merged. This is technically not necessary but might prevent incomplete or faulty code going to `master`.